# How to perform custom steps during Login POST method(using spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot

Spring boot provide its own implementation for login (POST method), if I want to maintain history(count) of successful/unsuccessful log in of users, how can I do it?

Comment: store that count somewhere db/file/cache etc?

Comment: I am planning to store it into db, but the login(POST) is provided by Spring Boot itself, how can I override it maintaining its original functionality, i.e. I want spring boot to do what it does originally but perform my functionality in additional.

Comment: I learnt about AuthenticationSuccesshandler and I have overridden its onAuthenticationSuccess, now I can perform what I was intended to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the following to make it working:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler{


@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ......
    }
```